# Align indentation to the equal sign

Tags: javascript, eslint, indentation, code-formatting, prettier

I want to align the indentation to the equal sign when formatting my code. Is there any plugin or setup out there?

Before:

```js
const React = require('react');
const MainContainer = require('../../components/container/main');
const HasAnyRole = require('../../components/auth/has-any-role');
```

After:

```js
const React         = require('react');
const MainContainer = require('../../components/container/main');
const HasAnyRole    = require('../../components/auth/has-any-role');
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is implemented in different IDE in different ways.

If you use **SublimeText** you can try this plugin: [AlignTab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AlignTab)

**Jetbrains IDE** [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-code-style-javascript.html):

> Settings | Code Style | Javascript | Variable declarations | Align |
> When multiline

Then

> Code | Reformat code

Answer (score 0):

depends on your IDE, IntelliJ has a setting for that

Comment: Maybe share where that setting is in IntelliJ, please?